# Removing the href value in a yii2 link

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a menu i have created in yii2 and i would like to remove the href value to #

This is what i have done

```
 <?php
            echo Menu::widget([
                'encodeLabels' => false,
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'topnav menu-left-nest'
                ],
                'items' => [
                    [
                    'label' => ThemeNav::link('Manager action, 'fa fa-user'),

                    'url' => ["#"],  //this is the url {{i}}

                    'options' => ['class' => 'tooltip-tip'],
                    'items' => [

                      ...items in the dropdown
                          ],
```

When i check on the inspect element The above url  ({{i}})   generates a value eg

```
<a href="/webwisekenya/advanced/backend/site/#"></a>
```

But i would like it to remain as

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

How do i go about this

This is the themenav class function link

```
public static function link($label, $icon = null) {

    $link = null;

    if (!empty($icon))
        $link .= Html::tag('i','',['class'=>$icon]);

    $link .= Html::tag('span', $label, []);

    return $link;

}
```

Comment: Instead of `["#"]` use just `#`

Comment: Thanks it works bizley, Post as an answer #bizley ill mark it. I had to add "", so the correct one is "#"

Comment: Accept the answer from @NiniGeek - it's the same as mine but he also added explanation and doc links.

Comment: Thanks ive seen it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Item list spécification, url can be defined as array or string:

- *array*: for predifined route
- *string*: directly the url

url var is used with the function [Url::to](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail). More info here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail

Manual about widget menu items: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html#$items-detail

Answer (score 0):

['label' => ThemeNav::link('Manager action, 'fa fa-user'),, 'url' => '#'],